# Checking if location services are enabled using react native

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, react-native, native

I am currently working on an app using react native that requires location services to be on for some of its features.  I have been researching if there is a simple way to test if the user has them turned on or not so I can display a different view if they aren't.  I have not found any results other than ones that are specific to IOS or Android.  Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Comment: when you call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is it not returning an error? http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#android

Comment: It can return an error.  But is that the most valid way to check it?  That could mean bad service or a number of things.  Is there a way to check the setting itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by displaying an error message when the location could not be retrieved.

```
(error) => {
        this.setState({servicesOn: false}),
        console.log(error);
      },
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the "react native android location services dialog box" module for android

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box

**install**

```
npm install react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box --save
```

**js**

```
import LocationServicesDialogBox from "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box";

LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
  message: "Use Location ?",
  ok: "YES",
  cancel: "NO"
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(success); // success => "enabled"
).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.message); // error.message => "disabled"
});
```

Comment: what about IOS?

Answer (score 1):

Do a watchPosition or getCurrentPosition, Your second argument is a callback in case of failure, and its argument is the reason it failed.

So, from there you know when and why it fails. You'll need an if for the reason if you only want to act on 'location disabled' and not 'request timed out' for example.

You can use the callback to add a flag to your state for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out these 2 libraries:

https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting

https://github.com/efkan/react-native-system-settings

What I have is the following:
I get this error **code 1** or error message: '*No location provider available*.' when my phone location service is turned off.

Other time, when it times out, I get this error **code 3** or error message: '*Location request timed out*.'.

Thus, based on the error code and message, I display different toasts to inform the user.

You can refer to this position error [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError) on MDN

[image]

Comment: I have used first library :). It's working fine but it will be better if we dont use any library.

Comment: does it checks the status continuously for the device? @Jun711