# Can I check devices location is open or close on React Native

Tags: geolocation, react-native

Can I check devices location is open or close before using `geolocation`?
I want to show alert message like `App need to run your location, please open your devices location`, when devices location is close.

Can I navigate to go native location setting both IOS and Android?

Like example -

```js
componentDidMount() {
  // Check condition device location is open or close.
  if( DevicesLocation === 'close' ) {
     alert('App need to run your location, please open your devices location');
     // other process 
  } else {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
           var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
           this.setState({ initialPosition});
        },
        (error) => console.log(error.message)
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the location permission on the device?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It's hard to understand what you are asking as it is.

Comment: @VladimirNul I will update soon!

Comment: @AakashSigdel yes premission to check only devices location is open or close. Please check again my updated question.

Comment: @VladimirNul , I updated my bad question. Please check again.

Comment: I think This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776780/checking-if-location-services-are-enabled-using-react-native

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
   //do stuff with location
  },
  (error) => {
    this.setState({locationEnabled: false}),
  },
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

For opening settings from your app, I think you will have to get your hands dirty with native code :D

Comment: how can I check location condition before using `geolocation`?

Comment: @LwinKyawMyat you can check it in componentDidMount() and onSuccess you can use geoLocation for fetching location.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

The `error` **no location provider is available** is thrown when `GPS` is not enabled its `error` `code` value is `2`.(log the `error.message or code` if you want to be sure).

```
const NO_LOCATION_PROVIDER_AVAILABLE = 2;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({ position });
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.code === NO_LOCATION_PROVIDER_AVAILABLE) {
         //Show alert or something here that GPS need to turned on.
      }
  },
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
export async function request_device_location_runtime_permission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'ReactNativeCode Location Permission',
        'message': 'ReactNativeCode App needs access to your location '
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

       Alert.alert("location active");
    }
    else {

      Alert.alert("location de active");

    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}


 async componentDidMount() {

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

      await request_device_location_runtime_permission();

    }

    this.getLongLat = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 100, distanceFilter: 10 },
    );

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.getLongLat);


  }
```

Comment: this will work with Android, what about iOS? Do I need to use another package?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nearit/react-native-connectivity-status

**Check Status**

```
import ConnectivityManager from 'react-native-connectivity-status'

// Check if Location Services are enabled
const locationServicesAvailable = await ConnectivityManager.areLocationServicesEnabled()
```

You can also **Subscribe to updates**

```
import ConnectivityManager from 'react-native-connectivity-status'

const connectivityStatusSubscription = ConnectivityManager.addStatusListener(({ eventType, status }) => {
    switch (eventType) {
        case 'bluetooth':
                    console.log(`Bluetooth is ${status ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}`)
                break
        case 'location':
                    console.log(`Location Services are ${status ? 'AVAILABLE' : 'NOT available'}`)
                break
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This package allows you to get the status of location service enabled/disabled without using geolocation.
https://github.com/rmrs/react-native-settings